# where is the source code for Oolong and Gnoloo?

Tags: jvm, oolong

I'm reading [Programming for the Java Virtual Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309726) which discusses the Oolong assembler and Gnoloo disassembler. Judging by references online the source code was at one point available, but I can't find it now. Does anyone know where to get it?

UPDATE: thanks to belisarius I have the code, and have [put it on GitHub](https://github.com/ymasory/programming-for-the-jvm) with some build automation to make it a little easier to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found them [here](http://scifac.ru.ac.za/resourcekit/download/index.htm) for download.

HTH!

Ps: there are several downloads in the page. [The one you're looking for is this](http://www.scifac.ru.ac.za/resourcekit/download/Engel.zip)

Comment: @Yuvi You're welcome :). The damn thing was pretty well hidden.